# Non-Kähler $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

As we know, a compact Kähler manifold always satisfies the $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma (see for example Huybrechts' book 《complex geometry》p128), thus we call it a $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifold, it seems not all the $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifolds are Kähler, but I don't have an example, so may someone provide one? The simpler the better.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/62492/21564

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261541/are-partial-exact-and-bar-partial-exact-forms-also-partial-bar-partial/261607#261607

Comment: @Arctic Char, the answer you post does not seem to give an $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifold, although it is non-Kähler?

Comment: The work of Daniele Angela may interest you.